# How could you find the probability that the estimator is within 0.03 of the mean?

Tags: statistics, estimation

p = fraction of large population that smokes

n = sample size

y = # in sample that smoke

The maximum likelihood estimate of p is  p-hat = y/n

Consider the random variable Y and estimator F = Y/n

How could you work out P(-0.03 < F - p < 0.03) knowing n and p?

This is what I have so far, I'm just not sure how to get rid of the st.dev variable:

let x be the standard deviation

Y ~ G(p,x)

Y-bar ~ G(p, x/ sqrt n)

P (-0.03 < F - p < 0.03) = P(p - 0.03 < Y-bar < p + 0.03)

=  P[ ((p - 0.03) -p)/(x/sqrtn) < (Y-bar - p) / (x/sqrt n) < ((p + 0.03)-p)/(x/sqrt n)]

= P (-0.03*sqrtn/x < Z < 0.03*sqrtn/x)

So how would I figure this out without knowing x (standard deviation)?

Comment: You estimate the population standard deviation using the sample standard deviation.

Comment: It wasn't given, otherwise I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Your "sample" is a collection of 0s and 1s, a 0 for each person in the sample that does not smoke and a 1 for each one that does. If these numbers aren't given separately, you can compute them: there are $n \hat{p}$ 1s and $n (1-\hat{p})$ 0s. Can you find the sample standard deviation now?

Comment: Okay, thank you. Then the follow up question is :suppose p=0.4. How large should n be to ensure P(-0.03 < F - p < 0.03)=0.95. I don't know how to do this unless Y follows binomial distribution. Did I choose the wrong distribution model?

Comment: $Y$ does follow a binomial distribution.

Comment: So doesn't that make my entire answer wrong?

Comment: Why would that make your answer wrong? The only thing you have done that needs some extra justification is going from $F-p$ to $Z$, which I assume means making a normal approximation.

Comment: Okay, so for the first part, my answer is complete if I define x to be np(1-p). Can you please tell me the complete answer for the second part? (how to find n so that there is 95% confidence)